# Not able to upload Youtube shorts video using youtube data api [ node js ]

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have referred the YouTube developer API documentation. I am unable to find any documentation for uploading a video as YouTube shorts using youtube data api

By referring internet i tried to add #shorts in description. But it didn't work for me

I have attached the sample code

[image]

Comment: Consider add the tag "shorts" on the tags of your video.

Comment: I tried adding shorts in tag in python but it doesnt post the video as shorts instead normal video is uploaded

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you're using.